# Are those two proofs equivalent?

Tags: coq

I just finished the exercises in here: https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html; however I came up with 2 different proofs for following exercise https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html#andb_true_elim2, and i would like to know

- is my first attempt is completely non-sensical? While it works, it requires introducing hypothesis `H : b && false = true` which is obviously wrong. ***How come I am not stopped from introducing such statement?***

```
Definition andb (b1:bool) (b2:bool) : bool :=
  match b1 with
  | true => b2
  | false => false
  end.
```

```
Theorem andb_true_elim2 : forall b c : bool,
  andb b c = true -> c = true.
Proof.
  intros b c.
  destruct c.
  reflexivity.
  intro H.
  rewrite <- H.
  destruct b.
  reflexivity.
  reflexivity.
  Qed.
```

- second attempt: No dubious hypothesis, and works.

```
Theorem andb_true_elim2 : forall b c : bool,
  andb b c = true -> c = true.
Proof.
  intros b c.
  destruct b eqn:Eb.
  intro H.
  rewrite <- H.
  reflexivity.
  destruct c.
  reflexivity.
  discriminate.
  Qed.
```

***Since Coq is happy with both proofs, they are equally good*** (I doubt this)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: @Nick Actually, it *is* about programming (as [proofs are programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) :)

Comment: Yes, I fear one would close every question on the `coq` tag with that line of reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a `False` hypothesis is something common and not at all problematic in Coq. In fact, if you look at the negation of a proposition `P`, it is defined as `P -> False`. In other words, you can derive a contradiction from having `P`.

There is even the tactic `exfalso` which proves any goal as long as you provide a proof of `False`. This means that if you have contradictory hypotheses then you can conclude your proof.

Here is an even shorter proof:

```
Theorem andb_true_elim2 :
  forall b c : bool,
    andb b c = true ->
    c = true.
Proof.
  intros b c h.
  destruct b.
  - simpl in h. (* h : c = true *)
    exact h.
  - simpl in h. (* h : false = true *)
    discriminate h.
Qed.
```

I use the tactic `discriminate` which closes the goal by seeing that `false = true` is impossible because they are two distinct constructors of `bool`.

Comment: Thanks! Important to stress that anything which  Qed. is happy with, is a correct proof. I was not sure about that fact, but it is.